# shell-builtin and built-in: duplicate tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was making a question related to bash built-in's and realise the existence of those two tags: [shell-builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-builtin) [built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/built-in)

[built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/built-in) tag has only 3 questions, no wiki and no followers, in my opinion all questions would also fit in [shell-builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-builtin).

[shell-builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-builtin) has 15 questions, with various shells and 1 follower.

Are those duplicate tags?

Wouldn't it be better if those tags are directly related to the shell itself like bash-builtin, csh-builtin, etc?

Answer (score 3):

Several upvotes but no answer?

I consider them duplicate. Apart from that IMHO tag names should be clear. Knowingly having these two for different purposes would most probably confuse a lot of people.

But I would not consider it useful to create bash-builtin, csh-builtin and so on. What is the advantage of `bash-builtin` vs `bash shell-builtin`? We have `fsck`, `ext4`, `btrfs`. Shall `ext4-fsck` and `btrfs-fsck` be added now? That would make sense to me only if serious problems were solved. Like avoiding problems with the 5-tags limit. But I don't think that is one.

Comment: on second thought, you are right. They would only make sense as alias tags, like `bash-builtin` => `bash` && `shell-builtin`, this will *cheat* the 5 tags limit