# What is the [history-expansion] tag for, and does it add any value?

Tags: discussion, tags

While reviewing existing tags (I was looking for Incident Response/Investigation related subjects) I came across the [history-expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-expansion) tag. Without a wiki definition I had to look at questions already tagged and assume it refers to expansion of the shell history, which will vary greatly depending on WHICH shell is the focus.

Is there value having a tag to distinguish this subject from [command-history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-history)?

Comment: Or, maybe I'm just too pedantic today? ;)

Comment: I'm failing to find the previous discussion I'm thinking of,  it my opinion at this point is to consider whether we'd have a set of history-expansion experts that are distinct from $SHELL experts who would follow the tag. I'm not sure it's worthwhile. I would recommend $SHELL + command-history.

Comment: Of *course* I find it after commenting: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1234/117549

Comment: I think it's a bit pedantic, yes. We also have [tag:brace-expansion] (brace-expansion works differently in different shells), and [tag:variable-substitution] (again, different in different shells).  On the other hand, we have the _very specific_ [tag:bash-expansion] for whatever reason.  Command history is something (relatively) completely different. Command history questions generally deals with the history as a whole, e.g. saving it, viewing it etc., while history expansion are more about how to interactively work with shortcuts for recalling specific commands.

Comment: @Kusalananda that is what meta is for I suppose. :)

Comment: I like the existence of this tag. I suspect this tag could be applied to many more questions, currently there's only 37. I would create a explanation stating that the use of this tag is for question that cover the expansion of history commands that is a feature provided by many shells.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, "history expansion/substitution" is not about "shortcuts for recalling specific commands". As explained in the `bash`, `zsh` and `csh` manpages, it specifically refers to a specific shell syntax where  `!` (which could be changed to another character in `bash` or `zsh`) is interpreted in a special way (being replaced with whole or parts of previous commands). It's not about interactive shortcuts like Ctrl-P, Ctrl-N Ctrl-R in bash (when in emacs editing mode).

Comment: + a form of command expansion also starts by `^`, and both `!` and `^` are also configurable in `csh`. sorry.

Comment: This seems to be one of those tags which only make sense if you already know the answer (as in, if the question author knows it’s called “history expansion”, they’d probably be able to answer their question; and by extension, editors shouldn’t add that tag to the question), or for questions about esoteric aspects of history expansion...

Comment: @StephenKitt I suggest that the tag name should be changed to `modifier-failed` in order to be sure that nobody is using it by mistake ;-)

Comment: @mosvy Well, I would call event designators "shortcuts" as they are used to avoid typing a full command (or part of a longer command).

Comment: I agree with @StephenKitt: Typically, `bash` users get strange error messages due to the [broken implementation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390931/bash-history-expansion-inside-single-quotes-after-a-double-quote-inside-the-sam) and will never guess that history expansion is the reason

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of good discussion and clarification of the idea(s) in the comments. I suppose that makes this a "successful" post for Meta-

At this point I believe there IS a distinct subject this tag addresses that provides value. The cause of the ambiguity for me was the lack of a concise description or wiki entry.

I would be happy to author one myself, but with my limited experience in this topic it is probably best for someone else to provide guidance on what [history-expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-expansion) represents.